# Weeding after parsing

Tags: java, c++, compiler-construction

After scanning and parsing. I am left with a sequence of valid tokens. I have rules that are not caught by the parser, for example "A class cannot be both abstract and final". Since there are many rules like this, how can I weed out these cases efficiently ?

I am writing my java compiler in c++

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/

Comment: Usually after parsing you have a syntax tree, not a series of tokens.  The next phase of compilation is typically some sort of semantic analysis where you check these invariants, and it's usually quite involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Rules" about valid structures typically are called "static semantics".   To process such rules, you usually need:

- The abstract syntax tree of the program, and of those entities that it references (e.g., other programs, classes, etc.)
- A symbol table, that associates with each identifier, the declaration relevant to that identifier, and the key information associated with that declaration, typically called the "type"
- The ability to compute the type of each compound fragment of text (e.g, expressions)

With this information, you implement essentially all the static semantics.  For instance, a "class cannot be both final and abstract" requires that the symbol for the class be associated with the properties final and abstract, that your parser/symbol do that association as it encounters the declarations, and that you in effect scan the symbol table entries after they are all constructed and check to see that both properites are not simultaneously present.   (You can implement this other ways, but the net effect is the same).

It is possible to check some things without all this machinery, if they happen to be accidentally, in your language, "near" each other.  I'm not a Java expert, but if "abstract" and "final" have to be declared on the same class declation, you might be able to hack a check that disallows those keywords near the keyword "class", but that would just be a hack and wouldn't be reliable in all circumstances.

You imply you are writing a (full) Java compiler by saying "your compiler" and "I have rules (that should be caught)".    You'll need to build all of the above, or simply accept somebody's else's completed version of all this.   You will find that building all of these elements aren't easy for people that are familiar with them, because modern langauges such as Java have very complex grammers, scoping rules and type systems.

Given that you seem unfamiliar with the need for these, and haven't even attempted to build an AST yet, I think your hopes of producing a result in the near term are not good.   I suggest you review your goals; if you are a student, you need more background before you start.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described the mechanics of your parser, but I would assume you are building up some form of [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) as you parse the source code. You should be able to easily plug the rules into this framework, as you create the nodes in the tree.

For example, you might have a C++ class for a Java "class" node, and when you construct this node while parsing, you could check any associated rules and throw an exception if any rule is violated.

Comment: i have a LR(1) grammer and i dont build an AST, all i have is a valid sequence of tokens

Comment: @Mike G: Then you have not yet "parsed" the code, you have only done lexical analysis. Have a look at http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/ for resources (including a tutorial) on lexing and parsing.